# Expanding disc partition of system running in vmware

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I run my Ubuntu in Vmware box. Unfortunately my Ubuntu disc size becomes too low. What is approach to solve this problem. I did expand partition in Vmwareand got message:

```
The disk was successfully expanded. You must repartition the disk and expand the file systems from within the guest operating system.
```

But how to resize disc partition in Ubuntu now?

UPD
output of fdisk -f

```
Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders, total 52428800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004819b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    39845887    19921920   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        39847934    41940991     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        39847936    41940991     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Do an `sudo fdisk -l` from inside the running system there.  Paste the output into the question.  Resizing will depend on whether it was installed with LVM or not.

Comment: I have updated question body with output

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so the solution for me was to use gparted, that allows you to move and resize partitions.

A nice tutorial of how to do it can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

1. Open "Disks" application (e.g. by hitting super key and typing "disks").

   [image: Disks Application]
2. Click on the icon with 2 cog wheels (⚙️), i.e., **Additional partition options** and then **Resize**.

   [image: Additional partition options]
3. Drag slider to the right.

   [image: Slider]
4. Click on "Resize" button.